# Determining if a form is used as a subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to determine if a form is used as a subform elsewhere? I have quite a few forms created and after some refactoring have some forms that I'm unsure if are used inside others.

If so, how do I do this?

Comment: Does Access 2013 still have "Track name AutoCorrect info" option?  In Access 2010, it is found at Options -> Current Database -> Name AutoCorrect Options.

Comment: @HansUp it does, but that would only follow through changed objects, not inform me of redundant objects, right?

Comment: That option causes Access to gather information about all objects, changed or not.  Then select one of those forms in the Navigation pane, and click "Object Dependencies" in the "Database Tools" section of the ribbon.  Then choose the "Objects that depend on me" radio button in the "Object Dependencies" pane.  That will show you which other forms (if any) depend on the form you selected.  This may not give you 100% of what you need, but it could be a reasonable start.

Comment: looks good! i think it's what i want! write it up as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider Access' *"Track name AutoCorrect info"* option.  When you enable that option, Access gathers information about database objects.  Afterward, you can select one of your forms in the Navigation pane and click *"Object Dependencies"* in the *"Database Tools"* section of the ribbon. That will bring up the *"Object Dependencies"* panel showing dependencies between the selected form and other database objects.  Choose the *"Objects that depend on me"* radio button and look in the forms section of that tree list to see which, if any, other forms depend on the form you selected.

Note if you have a form with a subform control, and change its `SourceObject` property at runtime ... IOW switch forms contained in the subform control ... Access may not identify any of those subforms as dependencies of the parent form.  So this approach may not give you everything you need, but it could be a reasonable starting point.

Finally, if this approach is useful, I suggest you disable the option after you're done.  Allen Browne describes problems due to *AutoCorrect* here: 
[Failures caused by Name AutoCorrect](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html).  I never leave any of the *AutoCorrect* options enabled in the production versions of my applications.

Comment: Very informative answer, thanks. And thanks for the heads up - I always feel uneasy with autocorrect after a few horrible coding nightmares with some simple refactorings in PHP!